# Load a properties file in java

Tags: java, python, properties, load

i am using java to load conf file which is using by python application:

```
[session_manager] 
host=1.2.3.4

[log_manager] 
host=7.8.9.1
```

I known that we have a Properties class to load a regular properties file in java. But this file is diffrent. Does java have any class to load that file, so that we can get properties like  that:

```
session_manager.host=1.2.3.4
log_manager.host=7.8.9.1
```

Comment: you want to convert it to like session_manager.host=1.2.3.4 ? or you want to read session_manager.host=1.2.3.4  in java ?

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](http://crunchify.com/java-properties-file-how-to-read-config-properties-values-in-java/)?

Comment: I want to read ession_manager.host=1.2.3.4  in java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not a properties file even if it is looking similar. Those are ini-files which can be parsed using [ini4j](http://ini4j.sourceforge.net/tutorial/OneMinuteTutorial.java.html).